# Is there a way to test the Kivy App before compiling to APK?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am developing an app in Kivy in which I use the plyer camera function which only works on android phones. so in order to test my code, I have to make an apk file (which takes ages using bulldozer) and once done I am unable to see what went wrong because the log files are very crowded on an actual phone.

1. So is there a way to check your code which only runs on android phones?
2. Is there a good emulator out there to test my APK?
3. Is there a debugger available which I can use?

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Question #1: Try the "Kivy Launcher" app (available on Google play  [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kivy.pygame&hl=en_US)).
2. Question #2: Use the "AVD" manager in "Android Studio" to create and launch an emulator. Then `buildozer android deploy run` will run the app on the emulator.
3. Question #3: There is an "adb" included as part of the Android SDK Tools. See [Android adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb).